# CMD - Copy null to multiple files

Tags: cmd, copy

I want to make lots of files 0 bytes on windows.
The command `copy /y nul test.vtx` was working. I need to change their size without changing the file names.

How can i use copy command to automatically detect the filenames and use them to erase its contents? Would be a bath file helpful?

Thanks.

Comment: try this, **break>filename**

Comment: But i have lots of files. Should i use *.vtx?
Also, it worked on singe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **break>** i don't know if it is possible anyway  you can iterate :

```
for %G in (*.vtx) do (copy /Y nul "%G")
```

Including subfolders :

```
for /R %G in (*.vtx) do (copy /Y nul "%G")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using PowerShell. When you are satisfied that the correct files will be overwritten, remove the `-WhatIf` from the Set-Content statement.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\src\t\adir -Filter *.vtx |
    ForEach-Object { Set-Content -Path $_ -Value $null -WhatIf}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]
     source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
       file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*").
    /CREATE :: CREATE directory tree and zero-length files only.
```

I see you specified "copy" but I assumed you or others might accept robocopy too. My guess would be:

```
    ROBOCOPY C:\vtxfolder1 C:\vtxfolder2 *.vtx /CREATE
```

Comment: But it doesn't empty the filles, it creates new empty files at another destination

Comment: I understood that was the point in the first place. But it could go:     ROBOCOPY C:\vtxfolder1 C:\vtxfolder2 *.vtx /CREATE | del vtxfolder1[backslash]*.vtx